# moodle.sty problem insterting graphics

Tags: moodle

I am attempting to make a moodle quiz and include a png image. Please find below my latex document. I am compiling with PDFLaTeX. The xml does not include the image.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[section]{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Use of English part 2}
    \begin{cloze}{A bad Habit}
        \includegraphics[width=6in]{badHabit.png}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item although
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item in
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item any
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item deal
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item at
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}[usecase]
                \item Whatever
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}
                \item it's
                \end{shortanswer}
        \item \begin{shortanswer}[usecase]
                \item Apart
                \end{shortanswer}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

My error is:

[image]

I have read other posts with similar issues. I tried to include --shell-escape=true to PDFLaTeX in texmaker but when I do on compiling I get the following error:
[image]

I'm new to LaTeX so please be gentle. I installed ghostscript and imagemagick like the documentation said. I couldn't run the optipng.exe (32bit, nothing happened) so I don't have that installed. Hopefully someone can run me through what is going wrong. Thank you!

EDIT 1: After checking the log files I see the process stopping.

```
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6in]{badHabit.png} for HTML...
<<extension .png(PNG) identified>>
moodle.sty: Converting 'badHabit.png' to base64...
runsystem(certutil -encode "badHabit.png" tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64
 > "badHabit.enc" && del tmp.b64)...disabled (restricted).


! Package moodle Error: Base64 conversion failed.

See the moodle package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

EDIT 2: With the --shell-escape flag included it seems now to convert the image. I am now running into an error about TeX capacity exceeded.

```
(C:\Users\AdamM\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6in]{badHabit.png} for HTML...
<<extension .png(PNG) identified>>
moodle.sty: Converting 'badHabit.png' to base64...
runsystem(certutil -encode "badHabit.png" tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64
 > "badHabit.enc" && del tmp.b64)...executed.

moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'badHabit.enc'...
runsystem(del "badHabit.enc")...executed.

Runaway definition?
->
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\g@addto@macro ...fter {#1#2}\xdef #1{\the \toks@ 
                                                  }\endgroup 
l.37    \end{cloze}
                 
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4461 strings out of 478582
 76562 string characters out of 2844344
 3000001 words of memory out of 3000000
 22585 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 472686 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,11n,77p,588b,536s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Which platform are you using? It seems that you miss the program to convert to  base64 (and yes, you have to run with `--shell-escape`). Please state also the version of `moodle.sty`.

Comment: Can you please state the version of `moodle.sty`? You can find it in the log (I'll add it to my answer). It compiles ok for me with `moodle 2021/02/07 v0.9` on Linux and an example image (I can't check with your image since it's not available).

Comment: @f1apjack When `--shell-escape` is used, does the generated XML file contain the base64 information ?

Comment: This error only appears when I use PDFLatex I don't get the memory error using LuaLatex

Comment: @F1apjack what is the weight of your file `badHabit.png`?

Answer (score 1):

You have some step in the conversion of the image that is not working. You can find which one by looking at the `.log` file; you should find something like this:

```
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6in]{example-image-c} for HTML...

moodle.sty: Converting 'example-image-c' to PNG...
runsystem(convert -colorspace RGB "example-image-c.pdf" -resize 618 "example-im
age-c.png")...executed.

moodle.sty: Optimizing 'example-image-c.png'...
runsystem(optipng -clobber -strip all -quiet "example-image-c.png")...executed.

moodle.sty: Converting 'example-image-c.png' to base64...
runsystem(base64 "example-image-c.png" > "example-image-c.enc")...executed.

moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'example-image-c.enc'...
runsystem(rm -f "example-image-c.enc" "example-image-c.png")...executed.
```

If you are in windows, the program that is doing the conversion to `base64` is something called `certutil` (yes, it should be mentioned in the manual, which is basically a documentation bug).

Notice that you **do** need the `--shell-escape` flag.

It is also important to state/check the version; you can find it in the `.log` file too:

```
(/home/romano/texlive2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moodle/moodle.sty
Package: moodle 2021/02/07 v0.9 Moodle quiz XML generation
```

Comment: I created an issue here: https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/-/issues/141

Comment: My log file says:

moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6in]{badHabit.png} for HTML...
<<extension .png(PNG) identified>>
moodle.sty: Converting 'badHabit.png' to base64...
runsystem(certutil -encode "badHabit.png" tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64
 > "badHabit.enc" && del tmp.b64)...disabled (restricted).


! Package moodle Error: Base64 conversion failed.

See the moodle package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

Comment: You sure you used `-shell-escape`? If yes, try to run the `certutil` command by hand and see if it works.